# New Identity Api's - Return Bearer Token and User Info

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I understand the built in /login added by .MapIdentityApi() only returns the bearer token, so I thought if i added my own I could return the userId after a successfull login, however it seems to be returning bearerToken and userId in a non deserializable way
Here is my code

```
app.MapPost("/customlogin", async ([FromBody] LoginRequest cmd, SignInManager<CustomUser> signInManager, UserManager<CustomUser> userManager) =>
{

    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(cmd.Email);
    signInManager.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, cmd.Password, false, false);

    return !result.Succeeded ? Results.BadRequest(result.IsNotAllowed) : TypedResults.Created("/customlogin", user.Id);
});
```

Here is what is returned

> {"tokenType":"Bearer","accessToken":"CfDJ8KI5ypqWuzxBtlvtldOiJEOLnkSRI-EyDfHTVMmiHIcltkiI51J1m38QDWKVbvubA2tv26p9M5jwFE0jKjnD2i9pq7gxJQOTyNlGig_SMxCUt4vdtziR6NpBjk3PNRLzET4L5Fk5bUb8LpxzjYeNRbo4pe0ybtBC13LZi7L_Xkziw2R-JHCD-iFhfkUaFXVWhVJLOWeTeKj7qh_Okr0LDt5tctxFypgMlF56J-5i9Rl8tCrDB4y_0r98uQS9rkP2qYRQ47rBCD6KP5LBtiMBt_INlb3udW_TNRUn0omDMg_osMgcid-RzaqXyWPcSj6y4TrQlRdWIP4GwmbOHqqSaKBVsyhrsSJnraOMKrElGqWYOqlnv09UY0KtJ0CiKQWkN3L3sfawXHRsYqMAm-3Qj1m6wr1hrKlweiwJzNkXd8rC7-oeeAfmRqMhiGeX_W7ffjeXhFgtF7fl6Jt0sFWgJOhD-xZHbhyR18XDlZuwSi-jeW7xSncPKVHQBXy91uSJx7UKQV2pcKIubzKO11mFsU07eLO9v1l8wgwPBfP2-BeYbeu6S-s30ex02pCYtCxqEF9k_lclpZ69XXjfObbwfA3dhTGptwXv8COEQO8GojmcNCv8ZySLoI7oJbmasbfG1L6HewJOUDKMC-VTgqcY8Xk","expiresIn":3600,"refreshToken":"CfDJ8KI5ypqWuzxBtlvtldOiJEPPADkJepY2j7GwBWIyH9pZQi9Frap3vIE1r_VJnx1OmsNpsgj0hk95JbSqKzQIp1zG1YQIFm56qPWqCDflQbBiLX0I7HHMrlZjl9BFfr_wbC-Y4zplpIXolrphOyIxwfJquVHrixiyJCtSjql7cfefwEurdmkdi7Kn0y5nm0IMYWJ3ofghX_VphzlmiRhwKna2NQZYL22t1Oxi-ENEHP1w7xsVWe2K1tk2ALvih01vp7Q_IM1B7CC3G2YRVZ_KSXPGVCRT7EUNdjk8wZz7UloZvRKvj3J8FPA0oFZsYGR5Lx9FX5N23Ixu6zvUw1LHsKGR4UFr3u6odZUPqFBz0xp7D1dmsbmGTSX0JVbVLJpSwYvpzm0Hl3VPaqiuopsgYoQeGVdptVqB17WCLN8yKWxLv2ONB6Ux1mEbBdR5iHuDmaIE5qBf4ntF4Wgb98g4yvKC8St-uDlxATnuBsq59ezjDlM6-3_nA-gx7YCMJ5D2NH7FK3k-oMeNGARh9wfCNgjv934aO8-8GEbNES7T6oAQBXmzFlqpXLpogc_Ll98hBKwY4kU2U4uxaqxKOHgfQKN9cF6XTXlBJIXEgPOeabdZdL28bgEYKPakUVjxpVXcpa3HShb9IbcyDtQU5tcZVHk"}1024"

If you look at the end of that, it has `}1024` where the number represents the userId

what is the proper way to get a userid after a successful lookup and also have the bearerToken so I can use to make other api calls with.

I am using .NET 8

Comment: What is your expected response here?

Comment: expected response should be 1024 since thats what I am returning, but preferably to format the actual response I am getting above in a better way/formatted so i can have all the info I want in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

SignInManager have impact on httpcontext. I cannot reproduce the faulty response you have got. From my understanding, it is better to request to default "/login" endpoint to get the default response and then add the custom property.

```
app.MapPost("/customlogin", async ([FromBody] LoginRequest cmd, UserManager<AppUser> userManager) =>
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(cmd.Email);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response =await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:7058/login", cmd);
    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    JObject jsonResult = JObject.Parse(result);
    jsonResult.Add("UserId",user.Id);
    var jsonString=jsonResult.ToString();
    return Results.Content(jsonString, "application/json");
});
```

[image]